# Trying to get Bulma is-active to work with REACT

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bulma

I'm working on a REACT app with Bulma css. My navbar has a logo linked to the homepage followed by navigation tabs to other pages. I want the current page tab color to be different, but for some reason my code isn't working.

```
<nav className="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation" >
    <div className="navbar-brand">
        <a className="navbar-item" href="./">
            <img src="./logo192.png" className="nav-logo"></img>
        </a>

        <a role="button" className="navbar-burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample">
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="space-nav">&nbsp;</div>
    
    <div className="tabs nav-tabs is-centered is-boxed">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="./myevents" onClick={() => handlePageChange('MyEvents')}
                    className={currentPage === 'MyEvents' ? 'nav-link is-current' : 'nav-link'}>
                    <span>My Events</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="./mytasks" onClick={() => handlePageChange('MyTasks')}
                    className={currentPage === 'MyTasks' ? 'nav-link is-current' : 'nav-link'}>
                    <span>My Tasks</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="./testing" onClick={() => handlePageChange('TestEnv')}
                    className={currentPage === 'TestEnv' ? 'nav-link is-current' : 'nav-link'}>
                    <span>test environment</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav >
```

I have the background-colour for `.is-current span` set to white, but the span element for the open page just won't turn white.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using React Router? Here is an example with Bulma...

```
<NavLink
  to="/messages"
  as="a"
  className={({ isActive }) =>
    `navbar-item${isActive ? " is-active" : ""}`
  }
>
 Messages
</NavLink>;
```